# How to loop entire led sequence?

Tags: python, led, adafruit

I am working on my first coding project (no prior coding experience). I have a WS2812B LED strip where I'd like to continuously cycle several LED patterns through.

If I only have the led pattern sequences, it will run everything once through and then get stuck in the last sequence (which I only want to run for 20 seconds).

I suspect I'm using too many while Trues or using them wrong. Is it the while True in this 3rd led sequence that is causing it to not start over?  I think I'm using the time = function wrong too.

I am using an adafruit trinket M0 and Mu to write, if that matters.

I tried putting everything within a while True: at the start. But the leds don't turn on at all if I do that.

While True:

## 1st led sequence code

## 2nd led sequence code

## 3rd led sequence code below

while True:
    if time = 20:
        break

```
testcol = (255, 255, 255)
ttype=type(testcol)
print(ttype)
#pixels[4] = (testcol)
pixels.show()

colors = {0:(255, 0, 0), 1:(255, 165, 0), 2:(255, 255, 0), 3:(0, 255, 0), 4:(0, 0, 255), 5:(0, 35, 200), 6:(255, 0, 255)}
ccount = len(colors)
#print (ccount)
#print(colors[2])

data = range(0,185)
chunks = [data[x:x+ccount] for x in range(0, len(data), ccount)]

for p in chunks:

    n = 0
    for subp in p:
        print ("this is chunks",p, "subpart", n,":",p[n], colors[n])
        wp = p[n]
        print ("this is wp:", wp)
        color = colors[n]
        print(color)
        pixels[wp] = (color)
        print(p)
        pixels.show()

        n = n+1

while True:
    t = random.randrange(1, 185)
    oc = pixels[t]
    pixels[t] = (174, 255, 0)  #Alitove String modification for GRB
    print("LED:", t, "has been twinkled")
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pixels[t] = (255, 255, 255)
    pixels.show()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pixels[t] = oc
    pixels.show()
```

Running check in Mu returns syntax error on if time = 20: before 3rd led sequence.

Comment: I am not just going to write the code for you but here are some hints 1) Your last while True loop is an infinite loop. If you want to make that your timing loop, use time.time() before entering the loop to set a starting time, and once in the loop, get current time and when > 20 seconds have passed, break out of the loop 2) Your code to alternate the light colors belongs inside the timing loop.

Comment: thankyou! I'll work on that.